Light switch and electrical socket placement from sink
What is the minimum requirement for a light switch and electrical socket placement from the edge of a sink? Also, can they be installed directly above and behind the sink on the wall (also within 12 inches)? I have been searching for the code (NEC) that addresses the requirements.

I think the only requirement, is that within six feet of a sink it must be protected by GFCI.  Common sense says expecting something to protect you all the time with electricity too close to water, might be wishful thinking.  Unless it must be that close because of good reasons(looking nice is not good enough), I would have it further away.

Here are the main NEC rules for locating outlets near a kitchen countertop sink:

210.52(C)(1) Wall Spaces.  Receptacle outlets shall be installed so that no point along the wall line is more than 600 mm (24 in.) measured horizontally from a receptacle outlet in that space.

There is a lengthy exception to the above rule that basically says receptacles are not required behind sinks if the sink is within 12" of the wall, but receptacles must be located within 24" of both sides horizontally.

210.52(C)(3)(1) On or above countertop or work surfaces: On or above, but not more than 500 mm (20 in.) above, the countertop or work surface.

That paragraph (C)(3) goes on and on, but basically, countertop receptacles must be readily accessible, and any receptacle more than 20" above a countertop doesn't count toward the required outlets.  NEC 2023 deleted the option to put a countertop outlet below the countertop.

Can they be installed directly above and behind the sink on the wall?

They can, but it won't count as a required receptacle.  The receptacle must meet the definition of "readily accessible", otherwise you would still have to add one on each side as well.  Examples in 210.52(C) mention spaces behind countertop sinks as being rendered not readily accessible.
This also means that a GFCI device may not be located above a countertop sink.

Can you explain more about the last paragraph?  My thinking is unless the receptacle is level/directly behind with the sink handles/faucets, then it should be as accessible as any other countertop receptacle.

@crip659 Middle paragraph of 210.52(C)(3) "Receptacle outlets rendered not readily accessible by appliances fastened in place, appliance garages, sinks, or rangetops ... or appliances occupying assigned spaces shall not be considered as these required outlets."  Basically countertop sinks follow the same rules as ranges.  Receptacles must be on both sides unless there's no countertop.
